# How to get id and name of the author from $_SESSION to database?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have problem on my website. I have editor of articles and I want to get to each article name and id of user who create this article. This data I give from `$_SESSION`. In file EditorController.php I have this code:

```
$managerUsers = new ManagerUsers();
$user = $managerUsers->returnUser();
$this->data['author'] = $user['name'];
$this->data['author_id'] = $user['users_id'];
$review = array(
          'reviews_id' => '',
          'author_id' => '',
          'author' => '',
if ($_POST)
            {
             $keys = array($author_id, $author, 'title', 'content', 'url', 
'description', 'keywords');
             $review = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($keys));
```

and in view editor.phtml I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="<?= $review['author_id'] ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="author" value="<?= $review['author'] ?>" />
```

but when I save article to the database this  two parameters aren't saved. I gave to the view this:

`<?= $author_id, $author ?>` and everything works OK, to the view is write id and name of the user who is now log in. So I thing that, there:

```
$managerUsers = new ManagerUsers();
$user = $managerUsers->returnUser();
$this->data['author'] = $user['name'];
$this->data['author_id'] = $user['users_id'];
```

isn't any problem. Please give me some advice where is problem and how to fix it. For all advices thanks to you in advance.

Comment: Also please share the ManagerUsers class.

Comment: Where are you using `$_SESSION` in this code? You probably shouldn't put this in hidden inputs, because the user can modify those in the browser console.

Answer (score 1):

**1) quick'n'dirty**

If you pass `author` and `author_id` through your form using hidden fields, you have to use these fields.

```
-$keys = array($author_id, $author, 'title', 'content', 'url', 'description', 'keywords');
+$keys = array('author_id', 'author', 'title', 'content', 'url', 'description', 'keywords');
```

**2) better way**

Leave those two keys out and add them directly

```
$keys = array('title', 'content', 'url', 'description', 'keywords');
$review = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($keys));
$review['author'] = $user['name'];
$review['author_id'] = $user['users_id'];
```

**3) maybe best way**

Kind of the same as 2, but add "template" `$review` before and merge form values.

```
$managerUsers = new ManagerUsers();
$user = $managerUsers->returnUser();
$this->data['author'] = $user['name'];
$this->data['author_id'] = $user['users_id'];
$review = array(
    'reviews_id' => '',
    'author_id' => $user['users_id'],
    'author' => $user['name'],
);
if ($_POST) {
    $keys = array('title', 'content', 'url', 'description', 'keywords');
    $review = array_merge(
        $review,
        array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($keys)
    );
    // do something with $review
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I used the second solution (better way) and everything works OK.